# Why return wrong results this program?

Tags: assembly, hla

I recently started working with HLA and  I can't find the error in this code. Please help me someone. Why return wrong results this program? 
The program is complete without any syntax error, but return bad values.

```
procedure program(VAL i:int32; VAL j:uns16; VAL N:uns32; VAR tomb: int32); @cdecl; @use EAX; @returns("EAX"); @external;
procedure program(VAL i:int32; VAL j:uns16; VAL N:uns32; VAR tomb: int32); @nodisplay;
begin program;
// tomb[0]=i+(j*9);
// for (k=1; k<N; k++) tomb[k]=(tomb[k-1]+9)*j;
// sum=0;
// for (k=0; k<N; k++) sum=sum+tomb[k]/15+i-j;
// return sum;

  PUSH(EBX);
  PUSH(ECX);
  PUSH(EDX);
  PUSH(EDI);
  PUSH(ESI); 

//Tomb[0]
  MOVZX(j,EAX); 
  INTMUL(9, EAX);
  ADD(i, EAX);
  MOV(tomb,EDI);
  MOV(EAX, [EDI]);  
  MOV(EAX, ESI); 
  MOV(N, ECX);

for1:
  DEC(ECX);         //ECX = ECX - 1
  JZ for1_end;      //if ECX = 0,
  ADD(9, ESI);      //ESI = (tomb[k-1]+9)
  INTMUL(j, ESI);   //ESI = (tomb[k-1]+9)*j
  ADD(4, EDI);  
  MOV(ESI, [EDI]);  //tomb[k] = tomb[k]=(tomb[k-1]+3)*j
  JMP for1;
for1_end:

//for (k=0; k<N; k++) sum=sum+tomb[k]/15+i-j;
  SUB(ESI, ESI);    // ESI (sum) = 0
  MOV(tomb, EDI);   // EDI = tomb cime
  MOV(N, ECX);      // ECX = N
  MOVZX(j, EDX);
  MOV(15, EBX);     
  ADD(i, EBX);
  SUB(EDX, EBX);    //15+i-j

for2:
  MOV( [EDI], EAX );// EAX = tomb[k]
  CDQ;
  IDIV( EBX );      // EAX = tomb[k]/15+i-j
  ADD( EAX, ESI );  // ESI = ESI+tomb[k]/15+i-j
  ADD(4, EDI);
  DEC(ECX);         // ECX = ECX-1
JNZ for2;           // if ECX=0,

  MOV( ESI, EAX );      // EAX = sum
  POP( ESI );
  POP( EDI );
  POP( EDX );
  POP( ECX );
  POP( EBX );
end program;
```

EDIT:

The `N` and `tomb` not visible for me. From `i` and `j` all i can-->

```
1. test case (i=7830, j=348):   result(for me):-15984526, correct:-1700110054 
2. test case (i=7830, j=913):   result(for me):-669363,   correct:-231479087 
3. test case (i=7830, j=3475):  result(for me):4404210,   correct:963858517 
4. test case (i=7830, j=-6588): result(for me):-674954,   correct:1719334650 
5. test case (i=7830, j=29684): result(for me):-6505388,  correct:-1490170292
```

Comment: 1) Don't use HLA. Like, ever. 2) Learn to use a debugger 3) At least provide expected and actual outputs.

Comment: @Celvin edit your answer ("edit" button on the lower left corner), don't post code as a comment.

Comment: Also, it's really tough to help you when your problem definition is, "Why return wrong results?"  What do you expect the results to be?  What does this code return?  Why do you believe that it is wrong?  Then refer to @Jester's post and use a debugger to step through your compiled binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // for (k=0; k<N; k++) sum=sum+tomb[k]/15+i-j;
> ```

Given this expression, it's wrong to calculate `15+i-j` and use that as a divider using `IDIV( EBX );  // EAX = tomb[k]/15+i-j`
!

Normal rules of algebra dictate that you need to divide by `15` and later on add `i` and subtract `j`.